# How to hash using DCPcrypt?

Tags: delphi, hash, cryptography, sha1, delphi-xe5

I have scowered the net trying to find an example of a function, how to hash text with Sha1 and DCPcrypt.

I have the below example. Seems to pop up the whole time.
But it returns chinese characters every time. Please assist in corecting the function.

```
function TForm1.EncryptThis(aString : string) : string;
var
   Cipher: TDCP_cast256;
   KeyStr: string;
begin
   KeyStr:= '';
   Cipher:= TDCP_cast256.Create(Self);
   Cipher.InitStr(KeyStr,TDCP_sha1);
   result := Cipher.EncryptString(aString);
   Cipher.Burn;
   Cipher.Free;
end;
```

**UPDATE:**
Using the links and info belowe, I built these functions. But as I said, This does not make alot of sense to me. So please excuse the ignorance.

THe code however does not work. Its output is: `3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F00000000000000000000` whereas it should be `40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef` since i told the program to has `123`.

Please help.

```
function CalcDigest(text: string): string;
var
  x: TDCP_hash;
begin
  x := TDCP_sha1.Create(nil);
  try
    x.Init;
    x.UpdateStr(text);
    SetLength(Result, x.GetHashSize div 8);
    x.Final(Result[1]);
  finally
    x.Free;
  end;
end;

function String2Hex(const Buffer: Ansistring): string;
begin
  SetLength(result, 2*Length(Buffer));
  BinToHex(@Buffer[1], PWideChar(@result[1]), Length(Buffer));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  memo2.Lines.Add(String2Hex(CalcDigest(memo1.Lines.Strings[0])));
end;
```

Comment: Don't confuse hashing (SHA1) with encryption (CAST).

Comment: I see @ArtjomB. but do you then have an example how to hash?

Comment: Rather than asking for code I feel you would be better served trying to better understand what these algorithms do. At the moment you are confused about their input and output. Hashes operate on binary, and output binary. Do you understand me when I say that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes i do understand. I did not know it but through this process it has become clear.... But I still need to figure out how i can get it to work asap.

Comment: Next step is to decide how to encode the input text as binary. ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16?

Comment: UTF-8 @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Then you need to use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes`, and pass that byte array to be hashed. What you get back is a binary hash. Then hex encode that for presentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan awesome thanks. But can you show me an example of how it would be done?

Comment: Maybe. But I don't use DCPCrypt. I think Indy is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [this](http://keit.co/p/dcpcrypt-hmac-rfc2104/), you can do it this way:

```
function CalcDigest(text: string): string;
var
  x: TDCP_hash;
begin
  x := TDCP_sha1.Create(nil);
  try
    x.Init;
    x.UpdateStr(text);
    SetLength(Result, x.GetHashSize div 8);
    x.Final(Result[1]);
  finally
    x.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You may want to encode the hash before printing, because the output is binary. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308049/converting-strings-to-hex-in-a-performant-way).

Comment: this is the result i get when trying to use that code on `123` `먋䙖쉮瘥歾싑䄿`

Comment: The output of a hashing function is binary. You will need to encode it as hex or base64 if you want it to print.

Comment: I am not sure how to best explain what i want. But basically visit this link and hash `123`, i want to be able to hash in delphi and show the same result in a memo field...http://www.sha1-online.com/... Basically the 2 must match.

Comment: Yes, that page does a hex encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308049/converting-strings-to-hex-in-a-performant-way

Comment: Can you be more specific please. I do not see it in that code... Please keep in mind i have never worked with hash codes before so it's a bit much to take in all at once...

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with DCPCrypt. You can also use other libraries.

1) Indy - usually included in Delphi

```
function SHA1Text(const s: string): string;
begin
  with TIdHashSHA1.Create do
    try
      Result:=LowerCase(HashStringAsHex(s));
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

2) Wolfgang Ehrhardt's libraries (fastest as far as I know) from
http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/crchash_en.html

```
function SHA1Text(const s: string): string;
var
  Context: THashContext;
  SHA1Digest: TSHA1Digest;
begin
  SHA1Init(Context);
  SHA1Update(Context, pChar(s), length(s));
  SHA1Final(Context, SHA1Digest);

  Result:=HexStr(@SHA1Digest, SizeOf(SHA1Digest));
end;
```

NOTE: it is from Delphi 7. You will need to update it if you use unicode Delphi.

Comment: I like the Indy idea, I have delphi xe5, it does have indy included but i am not sure which unit i must include?

Comment: These units should be sufficient: IdHash, IdHashSHA1